# How to get branching strategy for each item in changeset TFS 2010 C#

Tags: c#, tfs

I have a changeset. I get all the changed items and their server paths by associatedChangeset.Changes[x].Item.ServerItem. I want to get the branch and folder hierarchy of the item. I do not wish to go with spliting the serveritem value to get the branching. Is their any api that can get me the branch names for each item in a changeset?

Answer (score 0):

Not directly. The quickest way would be to send a query to the server for all the parent items  in the server paths to determine which is the closest branch folder and then query the branch hierarchy of that.  Doing this query efficiently from the client side will require quite a bit of work on your side.